# How to change compiler flags for Lineage OS build

Tags: android, lineageos

I have been trying to build Lineage 16.0 for my device n1awifi.
While trying to compile the OS I've been getting errors due to the `-Werror` flag being *presumably* set.

```
hardware/samsung_slsi-cm/exynos5420/mobicore/daemon/Daemon/MobiCoreDriverDaemon.h:57:18: error: unused parameter 'tci' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
    uint8_t *tci,
```

I thought about modifying the sources but due to most of the errors being in *again presumably* in libraries I don't want to be going through all of the sources modifying everything.

How should I move on with this project?